# Duda con doble negación en Singleton JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Me encuentro aprendiendo las **clases en JavaScript**, estoy con el tema de **Singleton**. Tengo una duda con el código.

```
class Singleton {
  static instancia;
  nombre;

  constructor(nombre = "") {
    if (!!Singleton.instancia) {
      return Singleton.instancia;
    }
    Singleton.instancia = this;
    this.nombre = nombre;
  }
}
const instancia1 = new Singleton("Hulk");
const instancia2 = new Singleton("IronMan");
const instancia3 = new Singleton("SpiderMan");

// Todos estos devolverán Hulk
console.log(`El nombre en la instancia 1 es: ${instancia1.nombre}`);
console.log(`El nombre en la instancia 2 es: ${instancia2.nombre}`);
console.log(`El nombre en la instancia 3 es: ${instancia3.nombre}`);
```

Lo que entiendo es lo siguiente, declaramos una clase Singleton, la cuál nos servirá para que al momento de instanciar una clase esta siempre lo haga de acuerdo al primer valor instanciado, corrijan si estoy equivocado, esa es la noción que tengo. Por ende si se vuelven a instanciar más veces, esta siempre tomará la primera instancia creada. Como en el caso de mi ejemplo que esta siempre devolverá **"Hulk"**. El valor static se agrega para que se pueda usar la variable **"instancia"** sin necesidad de tener que tener una instancia de la clase Singleton. Luego de eso de claro una variable **"nombre"** y en el constructor se le agrega un valor por defecto. Luego lo que no comprendo es lo siguiente, por que niega dos veces el **Singleton.instancia**. Lo que comprendo es: Al momento de entrar en el if , **instancia es igual a undefined ¿no es así?** por lo tanto este la niega dos veces, esto quedaría en ¿false?. Luego tampoco comprendo por que hace lo de Singleton.instancia = this;, luego se que asigna lo que se ingresó en nombre a nombre.

Esas son mis dudas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día,

La palabra clave `this` hace referencia al objeto de `JavaScript` en el cual se está ejecutando el código actual. En tu caso, `this` hace referencia a la clase `Singleton`.

Una forma fácil de verlo es mostrar en la consola `console.log(this);` adentro de la clase:

```js
class Singleton {
  static instancia;
  nombre;

  constructor(nombre = "") {
    if (!!Singleton.instancia) {
      return Singleton.instancia;
    }
    
    Singleton.instancia = this;
    this.nombre = nombre;

    /* Revisar lo que tiene this adentro de la clase */
    console.log(this);
  }
}

const instancia1 = new Singleton("Hulk");
console.log(`El nombre en la instancia 1 es: ${instancia1.nombre}`);
```

Como puedes ver, `this` hace referencia al objeto que lo contiene. Si únicamente pones `console.log(this);` entonces hará referencia al objeto global.

```js
/* Revisar lo que tiene this, objeto global */
console.log(this);
```

[Lectura recomendada](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Por último, la doble negación transforma los valores en su equivalente booleano, por ejemplo:

```
!!2; // -> true
!!''; // -> false
!!NaN; // -> false
!!'word'; // -> true
!!undefined; // -> false
```

Otra forma de hacerlo es utilizar la función `Boolean()` para hacer la conversión de forma explícita. [Lectura recomendada](https://codingbeauty.medium.com/javascript-double-negation-e667b993e408#:%7E:text=Double%20negation%20converts%20truthy%20values,true%20for%20a%20falsy%20value.)

Por lo que tu código podría quedar así:

```js
class Singleton {
  static instancia;
  nombre;

  constructor(nombre = "") {
    if (Boolean(Singleton.instancia)) {
      return Singleton.instancia;
    }
    
    Singleton.instancia = this;
    this.nombre = nombre;
  }
}

const instancia1 = new Singleton("Hulk");
const instancia2 = new Singleton("IronMan");
const instancia3 = new Singleton("SpiderMan");

// Todos estos devolverán Hulk
console.log(`El nombre en la instancia 1 es: ${instancia1.nombre}`);
console.log(`El nombre en la instancia 2 es: ${instancia2.nombre}`);
console.log(`El nombre en la instancia 3 es: ${instancia3.nombre}`);
```

Comment: Para extender un poco más, en JS todos los valores pueden ser evaluados como "truthy" o "falsy", es decir "verdaderos" o "falsos", pero sin ser realmente booleanos. Un objeto que exista ({})  es truthy, null/undefined son falsy, un string (cualquier string SIEMPRE QUE TENGA CONTENIDO) será truthy, un string vacío ("") será siempre falsy... entonces la doble negación lo que hace es lo siguiente: `truthy` (por ejemplo "hola") lo negamos y obtenemos un booleano "puro", y al volver a negarlo obtenemos el original pero "casteado" a booleano. Ej: "hola" (truthy) -> !"hola" (false) -> !!"hola" (true)

Comment: Gracias, estaba pensando como traducir "truthy" y "falsy" por eso mejor dejé el artículo que lo explica. Porque debería ser algo como "evaluados como verdaderos" o "supuestamente verdaderos" y "supuestamente falsos". No creo que haya traducción exacta al español para intentar reflejar lo que quieren decir.

Comment: Tambien para asegurarse de que un valor falsy/truthy sea convertido a un boolean primitivo se puede llamar al constructor 'Boolean' pero no con la palabra clave 'new' sino usado como función, por ejemplo Boolean('') o Boolean(0) castearan esos valors 'falsy' al tipo primitivo boolean con valor 'false'

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ Efectivamente es exactamente lo mismo usar `Boolean(valor)` que `!!valor`. Simplemente es más corto usar `!!valor`, y una vez te acostumbras a verlo como un *"operador"* más, es fácil de entender. Y pongo las comillas porque técnicamente `!!` no es un operador *per se*, pero es práctico y rápido. En cuanto a *truthy* y *falsy* no tenemos una palabra en español que encaje con esa... Además, la mayoría de gente en programación estamos acostumbrados a usar los términos "oficiales" en inglés, porque también decimos "booleanos" y no "tipo de dato lógico", "string" y no "cadena"...